# Oracle Need to return set number of rows even when no data found

Tags: c#, sql, oracle

Currently I have an oracle query that queries for some data and depending on the results groups them into "buckets". There should be a static number of these buckets regardless if data is found or not.

```
{ "Within 5 days", "6-10 days", "11-15 days", "15-20 days", "21-25 days", "26-30 days", "> 30 days" }
```

To handle this situation I am using a LINQ query with a string array of my "bucket" names and mapping them back to the query results. If no records are found I am simply creating a new object and setting all the values to 0 with the appropriate bucket header name (i.e "Within 5 days").

What I would love to do is just handle this without any C# code and have the oracle query return the empty rows with the hard-coded headers. My limitation is I am not an expert in Oracle and I also don't want to affect performance so I have been struggling with the proper and best way to handle this scenario.

Is there a way to strictly accomplish this if I modify the below query, where the case statement values are always returned even if there is no data to match the criteria? I know I can do a union all, but I have only seen this example on a single row not the need for as many as I am returning. The query below is a simplified version of the query I am running. There are 5 additional columns being returned that aggregate financial data.

```
   Select lag_time, NUM_DAYS
      FROM
         (SELECT  
            CLM.reported_date - CLM.loss_date as NUM_DAYS
          , CASE WHEN NVL(CLM.reported_date - CLM.loss_date,0) <= 5 THEN 'Within 5 days'
                 WHEN NVL(CLM.reported_date - CLM.loss_date,0) between 6 and 10 THEN '6-10 days'
                 WHEN CLM.reported_date - CLM.loss_date between 11 and 15 THEN '11-15 days'
                 WHEN CLM.reported_date - CLM.loss_date between 16 and 20 THEN '16-20 days'
                 WHEN CLM.reported_date - CLM.loss_date between 21 and 25 THEN '21-25 days'
                 WHEN CLM.reported_date - CLM.loss_date between 26 and 30 THEN '26-30 days'
                 WHEN CLM.reported_date - CLM.loss_date > 30 THEN 'greater than 30 days'
            END  Lag_Time                                
          FROM claim_table CLM   
          INNER JOIN policy_table IRP ON IRP.KEY = CLM.KEY                                
             WHERE IRP.POLICY_NUMBER in  ('12345678'))              
             group by lag_time
             order by lag_time
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` and a `PIVOT` to aggregate the buckets to columns:

```
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT POLICY_NUMBER,
         CASE
           WHEN CLM.reported_date IS NULL OR CLM.loss_date IS NULL THEN 'No claim'
           WHEN CLM.reported_date - CLM.loss_date <=  5            THEN 'Within 5 days'
           WHEN CLM.reported_date - CLM.loss_date <= 10            THEN '6-10 days'
           WHEN CLM.reported_date - CLM.loss_date <= 15            THEN '11-15 days'
           WHEN CLM.reported_date - CLM.loss_date <= 20            THEN '16-20 days'
           WHEN CLM.reported_date - CLM.loss_date <= 25            THEN '21-25 days'
           WHEN CLM.reported_date - CLM.loss_date <= 30            THEN '26-30 days'
                                                                   ELSE '31 or more days'
         END  Lag_Time                                
  FROM   policy_table IRP
         LEFT OUTER JOIN claim_table CLM   
         ON IRP.KEY = CLM.KEY                                
  WHERE  IRP.POLICY_NUMBER in  ('12345678')
) t
PIVOT(
  COUNT( 1 )
  FOR lag_time IN (
    'No claim'        AS "no_claims",
    'Within 5 days'   AS "within_5_days",
    '6-10 days'       AS  "6_to_10_days",
    '11-15 days'      AS "11_to_15_days",
    '16-20 days'      AS "16_to_20_days",
    '21-25 days'      AS "21_to_25_days",
    '26-30 days'      AS "26_to_30_days",
    '31 or more days' AS "31_or_more_days"
  )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the PIVOT command:

```
create table xxjk as
  select 'Within 5 Days' bucket, 5 n from dual union all
  select '6 - 10 Days' bucket, 7 n from dual;

select *
  from xxjk
 pivot (sum(n) for bucket in ('Within 5 Days' within_5_days,'6 - 10 Days' six_to_ten_days));
```

Extrapolate out to your own data of course.